# Invite email do not sent to non google account when sharing a calendar

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

C# package used: Google.Apis.Calendar.v3

I am making a sharing a calendar to an not google account.
No invite notification sent to that account event the Response = OK

```cs
            var rule = new AclRule
            {
                Role = "owner",
                Scope = new AclRule.ScopeData
                {
                    Value = acb@yahoo.com,
                    Type = "user"
                }
            };

            var service = await GetCalendarService();
            var request = service.Acl.Insert(rule, calendarId);

            request.SendNotifications = true;

            AclRule addedRule = await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

So could anybody help me about that?

Thanks,

Comment: Is an invitation being sent if you use the same code to send an invitation to a google account?

Comment: Sure, @ziganotschka. I got an email from sending by ACL api to a google account. But no for non google account.What I need is just an notification email to non google email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that google calendar API dont have any options to send notification to non google email.

Moreover, the calendar must be made as public first. This one can not modify by API. And I dont want to make it as public also.

Here's [document](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en&authuser=1) from google